# How can I save 2021-04-08T22:25:09.335541Z as timestamp to database in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, timestamp

I have a date string but this date's format looks like 2021-04-08T22:25:09.335541Z I couldn't saved to database

This is error message

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2021-04-08T22:25:09.335541Z' for column 'published_at' at row 1
```

I created published_at and it's date format is timestamp

For Example $table->timestamp('published_at');

I tried use Carbon::parse($publishedAt)->timestamp;

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1617920709' for column 'published_at' at row 1
```

returned it to me

Comment: It should just work with `Carbon::parse($publishedAt)`; Laravel should accept any instance of `DateTime` for `timestamp` columns, and I believe Carbon extends `DateTime`

Comment: The problem with the first is that mysql doesn't accept that date format with a `T` in the middle or a timezone specifier. The problem with the second is that mysql's TIMESTAMP type is not a Unix Timestamp, it still uses the `Y-M-D H:i:s` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Carbon to parse the date before saving it into database
in Your Model:

```
public function setPublishedAtAttribute($value)
{
     $this->attributes['published_at'] =  Carbon::parse($value);
}
```

Comment: Than you for your answers. It's worked